# Why memcache do not do anything on cronjob?

Tags: laravel, curl, memcached

I have one page on my website, which is very slow without any cache. The html on this page is very large, so I put the biggest part in the Cache. Unfortunately on this shared hosting there is only the Memcached service installed.

Because there is no other way to render the page and put it in the cache. I have created a cronjob, which is opening that page with cURL.

Unfortunately when i start the cronjob command from the shell and after that I open the slow page, it seems that the page is in the cache and it works fine.

But when the cronjob command starts from itself I get an email, that the job is done, but when I go to that slow page, it takes time to be rendered, so the page is not in the Cache.

I have tried that couple of times to be sure. Unfortunately I cannot check manual if the Cache key after execution of the cronjob is in the there, because the framework generates an unique key, so I cannot reproduce it.

Is it something from the Memcached service or maybe CURL ?

Comment: This seems little hacky to manually build the cache via cronjob, why dont you use larave;'s Cache facade to store the rendered HTML yourself?

Comment: i am using a package for storing the rendered cache - https://github.com/spatie/laravel-partialcache